# Getting Facebook group posts automatically in android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to implement the following feature in my android app.

We have a Facebook group and whenever a user post's something, it should be lively read on my android app(including post content,likes and comments).

Is it possible with currently available Facebook API's?.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage the group, you can authorize with the `user_managed_groups` permission and get the feed with `/group-id/feed.` There is no realtime API for groups, so you have to check for new items with a Cron Job (for example).

More information and example code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group/feed

Comment: Can I use an ajax call in a time interval function for getting new items?

Comment: of course, but only from your own server, after storing the times on a regular basis with a cron job.

Comment: btw, the whole concept is a bit problematic, because extended user tokens are only valid for 2 months. so every 2 months you have to refresh the token manually.